# Swift: how to parse json to a dictionary

Tags: json, swift

I have the following as a json output in console

```
{
    cash_machine = "0.08924368023872375488";
    dishwasher = "0.06437973678112030029";
    modem = "0.04461396858096122742";
    monitor = "0.28455805778503417969";
    nematode = "0.04982925951480865479";
    screen = "0.05664909631013870239";
    television = "0.03846205398440361023";
}
```

My code is

```
let session = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: r) { (data, response, error) in
    if let response = response {
        print(response)
    }
    if let data = data {
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
            print(json)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    // experiment here

    // if statement ends here
} .resume()
```

I was wondering how I'd parse this into a dictionary: `{"key1" : "value1", "key2" : "value2", "key3" : "value3", ..., "key_n", "value_n"}`

Comment: The result in `json` **is** a dictionary of type `[String:String]`.

Comment: Seems you already have a dictionary in the `json` variable. What's the actual problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try something along these lines

```
do {
    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String: String]
    for key in json.keys {
        print("\(key) : \(json[key])")
    }
}
```